# How to filter similar column values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I need help to extract data from one Oracle table called TEST which has this data:

```
Name      Description
Alex      IExpenses   
Mary      IExpenses Setup and Admin
John      IExpenses   
Brett     Internet Expenses Auditor
Todd      Internet Expenses Setup and Admin
Jane      Internet Expenses Auditor
```

So I need to select only data with condition where Description results don't return iExpenses (but include anything with iExpenses Setup and Admin) and don't return Internet Expenses Auditor (but include anything with Internet Expenses Setup and Admin).

How to create this condition?

Comment: What is desired result, based on this input?

Comment: I will try with REGEXP_LIKE, it will do the trick as i can see

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to return the results similar to those both cases, use

```
Description LIKE '%Expenses Setup and Admin'
```

for the *WHERE* condition

If case sensitivity matters then use

```
REGEXP_LIKE(Description,'Expenses Setup and Admin','i')
```

If those strictly those identifiers should be, then use an `IN` operator

```
Description IN ('Internet Expenses Setup and Admin','IExpenses Setup and Admin')
```

Moreover, if again case sensitivity matters, then use `i` option of `REGEXP_LIKE()` along with pipe operator such as

```
REGEXP_LIKE(Description,'Internet Expenses Setup and Admin|IExpenses Setup and Admin','i')
```

Btw, there's nothing to do with the exempted conditions which has already been satisfied through using options above.